# Script not working properly in crontab, but works when I run manually

Tags: bash, tomcat, cron

I have this is script set on crontab, which runs each 15 minutes. It mails me correctly with the respective messages, but when the server falls, the restarting command (/usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/startup.sh) doesn't restart Tomcat, but if I if run this script manually, it restarts!

```
*/15 * * * * /root/is_site_alive
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
s=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' 'http://www.nononono.com')
if [ $s == "200" ]; then
   echo 'java is UP' | mail -s "java  is UP" mail@mail.com
else
   /usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/startup.sh
   echo 'java is down - Restarting' | mail -s "Restarting" mail@mail.com
fi
```

---

**EDIT**

When I log the output of a run from crontab it says:

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

But when I run the script manually:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5.5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5.5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5.5/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre
```

Seems the user running crontab doesn't have knowledge of Java paths. Why is this happening?

Comment: Check the typical debugging questions in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: restart your server and put 2>/dev/yourlogfile.txt after the command ../../.startup.sh .. in the same line and see what's in the log and also see catalina.out file to see why.

Comment: @ArunSangal, you say this?  `/usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/startup.sh 2>/dev/yourlogfile.txt`

Comment: yes, and also see "tail -f /usr/share/tomcat5.5/logs/catalina.log"

Comment: @ArunSangal, I did as you adviced and made an edit to my post. Thanks if you can help me more

Answer (score 6):

The issue is cron jobs do not run as your user exactly as you are when you login via the terminal. This is because when you login as an actual user, your user shell profile—stored in `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `bashrc`—is loaded in as part of the login process. So user settings—such as system paths—are loaded in your session that you might not even be aware of.

So when it comes to cron jobs, your path info is missing because the cron task does not actually login as you, but simply runs the process as your user.

So while your cron job explicitly points to the file here:

```
/root/is_site_alive
```

The libraries, binaries & other items include in your system path when you login are missing. So processes within your bash file will basically be lost & unable to find the items they need to run.

A quick & dirty way to solve this problem is to to do the following. First get your `$PATH` like this from the terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

The output should be something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Now, within your bash script—and just after the `#!/bin/bash` line—ad that `$PATH` info like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
s=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' 'http://www.nononono.com')
if [ $s == "200" ]; then
   echo 'java is UP' | mail -s "java  is UP" mail@mail.com
else
   /usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/startup.sh
   echo 'java is down - Restarting' | mail -s "Restarting" mail@mail.com
fi
```

Now when you run that bash script, your expected path values will be in place. And the script should run as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a classic one with crontab. When you log to a unix like system, your shell reads at least your profile and/or system profile and depending on shell other init files. These init files usually set PATH and various environment strings.

But when a shell is started through crontab, none of these initializations occurs. So you have to :

- either source appropriate initialization files (not really recommended but can be a quick workaround)
- or carefully set all pertinent environment variable and use absolute paths (through variables) for all commands outside /bin and /usr/bin

Example :

```
#! /bin/sh
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
JAVA=/path/to/java/bin/java

$(JAVA) -jar app.jar param1 param2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another efficient solution**

if your user has a home directory and has some environment variables, for example /homedir/user1/ then you can apply this

```
#!/bin/ash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Or it depends on distrib, maybe you'll have to add this instead :

```
#!/bin/ash
source $HOME/.profile
```

With the "source" line you'll have access to the user's environment variables.

Or you can instead specify this inside the cron file :

```
*/15 * * * * source $HOME/.bash_profile; /root/is_site_alive
```

**The most important point is that you avoid mistakes by copying some environment variables.**

HOME is a POSIX standard and will be set even when you execute your script via a cron job. LOGNAME is also a posix standard and should be used instead of USER.